# Change page length control from dropdown to links

Tags: jquery, datatables

I was wondering if the `Records per page` dropdown options can be changed to a set of links. I couldn't find anything related in the docs and would like to know if this is possible at all.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option for this, but you should be able to put it together using `buttons` and `page.len()`

https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons

https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`page.len()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()) API method to set page length.

Basic example to use links to set page length:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   dom: '<"#example-page-length">frtip',
   lengthMenu: [ 15, 25, 50 ],
   initComplete: function(){
      $('#example-page-length').html(
         'Records per page: <a href="javascript:;">15</a> <a href="javascript:;">25</a> <a href="javascript:;">50</a>'
      );
   }
});

$(table.table().container()).on('click', '#example-page-length a', function(){
   table.page.len($(this).text()).draw();
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etLrph4o/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Briliant API-mining!